# Calling Javascript from Robotframework Browser Library.. myGoToKeyword is not defined

Tags: javascript, robotframework, playwright-python

I am following the instructions detailed here on extending with Javascript
https://github.com/MarketSquare/robotframework-browser

However I get an error "No keyword with name 'myGoToKeyword' found." when I run the test.

Should I be calling with "Execute Javascript".
I get a different error if I do that...

> Error: page.evaluate: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: myGoToKeyword is not defined

- at eval (eval at evaluate (:338:25), :1:1)"
- at eval ()
- at UtilityScript.evaluate (:338:25)
- at UtilityScript. (:1:44)

Comment: Post your code or give a more complete example of what you are doing.

Comment: Code is exactly as per example given...async function myGoToKeyword(page, args) {
  return await page.goto(args[0]);
}
exports.__esModule = true;
exports.myGoToKeyword = myGoToKeyword;

Comment: Ah ! Fixed - Thanks I had a couple of Resource import declarations before my Library import declaration -it's working when I put the Library one first.